# Which built-in .NET exceptions can I throw from my application?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

If I need to throw an exception from within my application which of the built-in .NET exception classes can I use? Are they all fair game? When should I derive my own?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2005/03/27/402801.aspx Comments on that post are also useful.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

See [Creating and Throwing Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173163.aspx).

On throwing built-in exceptions, it says:

> Do not throw System.Exception, System.SystemException, System.NullReferenceException, or System.IndexOutOfRangeException intentionally from your own source code.

and

> Do Not Throw General Exceptions
>
> If you throw a general exception type, such as Exception or SystemException in a library or framework, it forces consumers to catch all exceptions, including unknown exceptions that they do not know how to handle.
>
> Instead, either throw a more derived type that already exists in the framework, or create your own type that derives from Exception."

This [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2007/01/22/faq-what-exception-should-i-throw-instead-of-the-reserved-exceptions-found-by-donotraisereservedexceptiontypes.aspx) also has some useful guidelines.

Also, FxCop code analysis defines a list of "do not raise exceptions" as [described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx).  It recommends:

> The following exception types are too general to provide sufficient information to the user:
>
> - System.Exception
> - System.ApplicationException
> - System.SystemException
>
> The following exception types are reserved and should be thrown only by the common language runtime:
>
> - System.ExecutionEngineException
> - System.IndexOutOfRangeException
> - System.NullReferenceException
> - System.OutOfMemoryException

So in theory you can raise any other framework exception type, providing you clearly understand the intent of the exception as described by Microsoft (see MSDN documentation).

Note, these are "guidelines" and as some others have said, there is debate around System.IndexOutOfRangeException (ie many developers throw this exception).

Comment: Why not IndexOutOfRandeException? What happens when you have a index accessor ( this[int index] ) and the supplied value is out side the range of the items you have?

Comment: I would exclude: System.IndexOutOfRangeException, there is enough reason for you to throw one yourself.

Comment: re IndexOutOfRangeException, it is a question I have also.  The text is from the linked article.

Comment: I would throw IndexOutOfRangeException when applicable. Seems to be in the same group as ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException and the like and I don't see a reason not to use one of these.

Comment: I think they want you to use System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException instead of System.IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @Sekhat I guess in that scenario you should just attempt the index access instead of trying to check and raise your own exception; you're going to end up with an IndexOutOfRangeException if there was an issue.

Answer (score 8):

On the subject of `System.Exception` and `System.ApplicationException`: The latter was meant to be used as the base class of all custom exceptions. However, this hasn't been enforced consistently from the beginning. Consequently, there's a controversy whether this class should be used at all rather than using `System.Exception` as the base class for all exceptions.

Whichever way you decide, *never* throw an instance of these two classes directly. It's actually a pity that they aren't `abstact`. For what it's worth, always try using the most specific exception possible. If there is none to meet your requirement, feel free to create your own. In this case, however, make sure that your exception has a benefit over existing exceptions. In particular, it should convey its meaning perfectly and provide all the information necessary to handle the situation in a meaningful manner.

Avoid to create stub exceptions that don't do anything meaningful. In the same vein, avoid creating huge exception class hierarchies, they're rarely useful (although I can imagine a situation or two where I would use them … a parser being one of them).

Answer (score 6):

I use the [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (and its “friends”) regularly.

[`NotSupportedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`NotImplementedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notimplementedexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) are also common.

Answer (score 5):

My advice would be to focus on two things:

1. Scenarios
2. User expectations

In otherwords, I would sit down and identify:

1. Under what scenarios do you want to throw exceptions.
2. In those scenarios, what would the users of your API expect

The answer to #1 is, of course, application specific. The answer to #2 is "what ever similar code they are already familiar with does".

The behavior that comes out of this is:

1. Under the scenarios that arise in your programs that also arrive inside the
   framework, such as arguments being null, out of range, being invalid, methods not
   being implemented, or just not supported, then you should use the same exceptions the
   framework uses. The people using your APIs are going to expect that they behave that
   way (because that's how everything else behaves), and so will be better able to use
   your api from the "get go".

   2. For new scenarios that don't exist in the framework, you should go ahead and invent 
      your own exception classes. I would say that you should prefer Exception as your base 
      class unless their is some other base exception that provides services you need. 
      Generally speaking I don't think something like "ApplicationException" will help you 
      much. When you start defining your own exceptions there are a few things you should 
      keep in mind though:

   a. The primary purpose of an exception is for human communication. They convey 
      information about something that happened that shouldn't have. They should provide 
      enough information to identify the cause of a problem and to figure out how to 
      resolve it.

   b. Internal consistency is extremely important. Making your app behave as universally 
      as possible under similar circumstances will make you API's users more productive.

As far as there being hard and fast rules about what you should and should not do... I wouldn't worry about that stuff. Instead I would just focus on identifying scenarios, finding the existing exception that fits those scenarios, and then carefully desining your own if an existing one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can create and throw pretty much any of them, but you generally shouldn't. As an example, the various argument validation exceptions (ArgumentException, ArgumentNullException, ArgumentOutOfRangeException, etc) are suitable for use in application code, but AccessViolationException isn't. ApplicationException is provided as a suitable base class for any custom exception classes you may require.

See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/seyhszts.aspx) for a list of best practices - it refers to handling exceptions, but also contains good advice on creating them...

Comment: `ApplicationException` should no longer be used as a base class for custom exceptions. This used to be the case, but Microsoft learned that it is not useful. Use `Exception` as the base for your own exceptions.

Answer (score -1):

For more current .NET ecosystem coding conventions, see [Handling and throwing exceptions in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/). As is said elsewhere, throwing the `Exception` exception class is **not** good practice and should only be used as a base class. As far as list of exceptions, there's a table of [common exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/#common-exceptions). A somewhat messy but more complete method is to look at the [System.Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception) class documentation and expand the inheriting classes list. Scroll through the list of inheriting classes, look for a name that sounds good to you, then read further in *that* exception's documentation for usage guidelines.