# C#: Exception to throw when a certain type was expected

Tags: c#, exception

I know this sort of code is not best practice, but nevertheless in certain situations I find it is a simpler solution:

```
if (obj.Foo is Xxxx)
{
   // Do something
}
else if (obj.Foo is Yyyy) 
{
   // Do something
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Type " + obj.Foo.GetType() + " is not handled.");
}
```

Anyone know if there is a built-in exception I can throw in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `obj` is an argument to the method, you should throw an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx):

```
throw new ArgumentException("Type " + obj.Foo.GetType() + " is not handled.", "obj");
```

Otherwise, you should probably either throw an [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx) or create your own exception, like this:

```
///<summary>The exception thrown because of ...</summary>
[Serializable]
public class MyException : Exception {
    ///<summary>Creates a MyException with the default message.</summary>
    public MyException () : this("An error occurred") { }

    ///<summary>Creates a MyException with the given message.</summary>
    public MyException (string message) : base(message) { }
    ///<summary>Creates a MyException with the given message and inner exception.</summary>
    public MyException (string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    ///<summary>Deserializes a MyException .</summary>
    protected MyException (SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `System.NotSupportedException` or just make your own exception based on Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://www.mobydisk.com/softdev/techinfo/dotnetexceptions.html) for a comprehensive list of exceptions. Unfortunately, I don't think any of them fits your problem. It's better to create your own.

Comment: And I suggest you name it UnsupportedTypeException. :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps System.InvalidOperationException (whatever operation your method is meant to do cannot be done on this data type) ? Or make your own as the others are suggesting

Answer (score 0):

If obj is a parameter to your method, I'd throw an [`ArgumentException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentexception.aspx). Otherwise, in this case, I'd probably roll my own.

See [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218150/which-built-in-net-exceptions-can-i-throw-from-my-application) for a rundown on exception guidelines. Basically, there's some built in exceptions that are considered off limits to throw outside the framework. `ArgumentException` is one of them that is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Coincidentially, today i found a very nice class from Jared Pars's Weblog, [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/05/16/switching-on-types.aspx) where he explains a SwitchType class for dealing with this kind of situations.

Usage:

```
TypeSwitch.Do(
    sender,
    TypeSwitch.Case<Button>(() => textBox1.Text = "Hit a Button"),
    TypeSwitch.Case<CheckBox>(x => textBox1.Text = "Checkbox is " + x.Checked),
    TypeSwitch.Default(() => textBox1.Text = "Not sure what is hovered over"));
```