# Is there a list of .Net Exception types and advice on when to use them?

Tags: .net, exception

Does anyone know of a list of .Net Exception types .e.g. `ArgumentNullException` and under what circumstances you should use them? At the moment I'm just guessing based on the type name but I would rather get it right.

Comment: I don't know of a list perse, but I know that MSDN will tell you what most exceptions are for. Isn't that good enough?

Comment: Take a look at this MSDN topic: [SystemException Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.systemexception.aspx)

Comment: Yes MSDN will give you a list but to browse through msdn each time looking at each page for each exception to work out which one to choose will take ages. What we need is a summary of most common exceptions and friendly advice on when you would use each of them

Comment: Arrghh that's no good - throwing SystemException each time is exactly what we *shouldn't* be doing

Comment: this topic contains the list of exceptions :).  That is why I posted a link to it here :)

Comment: oh yes so it does (when you click "more"), my bad. What we need now is to pull all that text into one place so we can see at a glance

Comment: Generally, it is possible to grab this information from the MSDN and create a single document. But I think, it will be too large ... to be able to see it at a glance ;-)

Comment: Even though "More..." will reveal more exceptions the list is far from complete, since it only reveals the exceptions which inherit directly from System.Exception. The hierarchy is deeper than the one level shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which built-in .NET exceptions can I throw from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218150/which-built-in-net-exceptions-can-i-throw-from-my-application) Flagging an older duplicate.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

A list of them:

http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/net-exceptions-all-of-them/

As for the circumstance, it depends, most of the time they make sense based on their name and arguments.  `ArgumentNullException`, for example, is usually used when checking method / constructor arguments for null values.

Then you have others such as `FileNotFoundException`, `NullReferenceException`, `InvalidOperationException`, as you can see they read very easily and should be used with common sense.

**Update 1:** as someone has suggested, they are also on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx#inheritanceContinued

Here are views on common exceptions available:

https://blogs.msmvps.com/jgaylord/2009/07/08/common-and-all-system-exceptions-in-net/

http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1889/exception-handling-in-c/3/

**Update 2:** as for usage, Microsoft has guidelines for reserved exception types:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182338.aspx

Comment: This is also an interesting read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx

Comment: @Paulo indeed, that one has gone on my instapaper for later :-)

Comment: Nice list of lists! The first list is formatted painfully, but good information, especially @Paulo's msdn link.