# Exception catched as System.AggregateException

Tags: c#, exception

After executing this code:

```
try
{
    DoSomething();
}
catch (TaskCanceledException e)
{
    DealWithCancelledTaskException(e);
    throw;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    DealWithNormalException(e);
    throw;
}
```

The exception is raised.
`DoSomething` is supposed to throw `TaskCancelledException`, but it throws `System.AggregateException` containing one exception of type `TaskCancelledException` and is caught as normal `Exception`.

How can I catch this exception as `TaskCancelledException`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [list of exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376829/list-of-exceptions)

Comment: you would get `Aggregate` exception , hence it is caught has normal exception

Comment: Task-related exceptions are always raised as AggregateException, where the InnerException member is the actual exception you are interested in.

Comment: It's probably `AggregateException` like @Jaya wrote, but it's impossible to guess what `DoSomething` does. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: It's `System.AggregateException`

Comment: The question is why are you mixing synchronous and asynchronous code? The golden rule is "async all the way". This way you wouldn't get an AggregateException, because "await" unwraps these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is most likely that your code is throwing an [AggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Firstly try explicitly catching AggregateException. Then to access the exception that has been wrapped up by the aggregate exception use the `InnerException` Property. You can also access the list of all exceptions that have been aggregated (if there is or could be more than 1) by accessing the `InnerExceptions` property which gives you a list of the exceptions that this exception has aggregated