# What is the "correct" exception type to throw for an error in an external application?

Tags: .net, exception, base-class-library

I have a helper method that shells out to an external (command line) utility. Upon process completion it checks the exit code and if it detects an error throws an exception with the contents of StandardError.

I realize that it doesn't terribly matter for my given scenario. But what is the "correct" exception type for an error in an external application.

I remember a long time ago seeing a list somewhere on msdn of all the built-in exception types and their recommended uses but can no longer find it.

Comment: Your own exception type>

Comment: For a list of exceptions, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676021/is-there-a-list-of-net-exception-types-and-advice-on-when-to-use-them

Comment: Yes, a user defined exception.

Answer (score 1):

The "correct" exception is the one that you define in your application.

Just be sure that hold an internal Exception Dictionary that you can work with.

If you document your Exception Dictionary and use it as intended it works wonders both inside your applications and to others that will have to deal with them.

General Exceptions are.... general (doh!) and cannot provide sufficient insight to the real problem to the ones using your application.

My2c